# Connect from Mac to PC with terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, connection, smb

how can we do to **connect to a PC folder with the Mac Terminal** ?

For example with the Terminal I would like to go to:

**smb://PCServer01/Folder01/FinalFolder**

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you're looking for is `open`.

`open` takes an URL argument and can open files, applications, folders, web pages, ...

See `man open`.